# Replacing null checks using ploymorphism

Tags: design-patterns, polymorphism

Recently I was reading through the book "clean code" by Robert Martin, and in chapter 7 there was a section where he said you should try to replace null checks using the special case design pattern. I thought this was a great idea but then I thought about the following instance.

```
foreach(thing in someCollection) {
    value = getValue();
    if(value == null) {
        break;
    }
    value.doSomething();
}
```

You could make it so the object returned by `getValue` is polymorphic, create an interface that has the `doSomething()` method enforced and implement it for the object you wish to return, and "mock" class for the spcial case (if the value is null). This would eliminate the need for a gaurd clause as it doesn't really matter if `doSomething()` is called on our "mock" object as it is an actual object which has the `doSomething()` method:

```
 function doSomething(){
    return;
 }
```

the only issue is, the loop doesn't break. As far as I can tell there is no way of breaking out of a loop using a polymorphic class if a "mock" object is returned, unless you have a check for the mock object but then that defeats the point.

My question is, is there a clean way of dealing with nulls that don't incur this computation penalty? Or am I misunderstanding something about what is said in chapter 7 around null checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the `break` is to prevent a `NullPointerException` because the end of the collection has been reached. If the goal is rather to *filter* the collection, a more appropriate construct (such as a `Predicate`) would be warranted (and more readable).

At a high level, you've observed that dropping a small OO construct into a batch of procedural code can require rethinking more of the previous design. This is often true. If `null` is used as a break point in the middle of a collection, there is a bigger design issue to consider before implementing the null-object pattern.

While this could still be a good scenario for the null-object pattern (after refactoring the loop) the pattern is not applicable to every scenario where `null` is used. Unfortunately, it's not that simple. `Optional` is one more popular solution and there are more.

Answer (score 2):

The special case pattern or null object pattern is used to treat all cases uniformly. It relieves the client code from having multiple execution paths.

In the example you gave, the special case has to be treated differently because the iteration must be stopped when a certain value is encountered (`null` in this case). You can't apply a solution for problem X to solve problem Y, especially when both problems are complete opposites.